# Mail Gun Sending via HTTP returns Server response: 550 5.1.0 Recipient rejected

Tags: php, curl, mailgun

```
$ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/domain.com/messages');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('from' => 'Excited User <administrator@domain.com>',
                                                 'to' => 'tester@otherdomain.com',
                                                 'subject' => 'test',
                                                 'text' => 'message'));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Above is a snippet of my send function. if i user gmail, or yahoo or aol on the otherdomain, the message is sent. but if I use a custom otherdomain, it returns a Server Response: 550

What did I miss?

Answer (score -1):

I found out that when you use mailgun's incomming smtp, the previois emails will not be available. you have to input them again on their mailbox.

Comment: I'm trying to send through mailgun via MediaWiki and the Mailgun extension. It's not working. The logs at Mailgun.com show the error description as "Server response: 550 550 Messages should have one or no From headers, not 2."  However, the message content (and headers) that I see in those same logs do not show more than 1 from header.  Bottom Line: I've got a similar error, but I don't know what the resolution is.  This answer is confusing and makes no sense to me.